# The right thing to say?

Tags: blessing

Why do most sefaradim don't use the pasuk as used by Boaz: A-donai imachem but replace it by Ha-shem imachem?
Is this wrong piety?

Comment: Hashem means Gd

Comment: Are you referring to a statement before reading the Torah?

Answer (score 1):

In a similar way to the way we write the Name we do not say the sacred Names explicitly unless as part of a bracha
 Even when speaking about a bracha we say Hashem and not the Name as written
 Thus when quoting a pasuk on speech we do this as well. Since it is nonsacred speech, we avoid the sacred Name.

As an example, we see in [kiddushin 71a](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.71a?lang=bi)

> “This is My name forever [le’olam]” (Exodus 3:15), which is written so
>   that it can be read le’alem, to hide. This indicates that the Divine
>   Name must remain hidden. The Gemara relates: Rava planned to expound
>   and explain the proper way to say the name in a public discourse. A
>   certain elder said to him: It is written so that it can be read
>   le’alem, indicating that it must stay hidden.

Comment: Kiddushin 71a regarding זה שמי לעולם זה זכרי לדר ודר. As you’re posting here on your phone, I assume you have a smartphone? Why don’t you download the Sefaria app? They have for both iOS and Android.

Comment: You should be able to just press and hold on the source in Sefaria until the copy option shows up. Even without that, though, you should be able to just write out the source, as I did above.